# Using SSH keys with pygithub

Tags: python-3.x, github-api, pygithub

How do I authenticate with github.com using pygithub and ssh keys?

I can authenticate just fine with an access token. For various corporate type reasons, it would be extremely convenient to use SSH keys for the script I am writing.

I have found a few articles about using SSH keys with the "git" library. But, they mainly seem to operate on local data for a repo that is already cloned and it doesn't seem to be applicable to pygithub.

```
conn = github.Github(ACC_TOKEN)
#conn =github.Github("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub") # it would be wonderful if this worked.

repo = conn.get_repo(reponame)
```

I would have hoped that the commented out line would have worked.

Also, I don't want to clone a repo or anything. I need to be able to interact with things without cloning.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Did you get any updates?

Comment: I did not. I'll have to dig up the script. Iirc, I ended up just writing a wrapper library around the command line git.